# Golang - Create custom logger to share on files and packages across app

Tags: go

In my program there is a lot places where I should  create logs like following

```
log.Println("[Build]: bla bla“)

log.Println(“[INFO]: bla bla“)

log.Printf(“[ERROR]: bla bla“)

log.Println(“[WARNING]: bla bla“)
```

I use it for all my logging in different packages inside the application
and it’s bit frustrating to copy this, is there a way to create some generic 
log which I can simple re-use it inside my program.

I read about logrus etc but they provide some way to do it but not provide some custom way or 
maybe I miss something.

My program is command line tool

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking here... can you create re-usable code? Yes, that's the purpose of functions and methods and most programming language features in every language.

Comment: @Adrian - This is not what Im talking about, my question if there is option to extend the log api or other logs api of go to support this secnario

Comment: You've already extended the API, you're just doing it by copy and pasting. You could easily write a function or a type that does the same thing.

Comment: @Adrian - im not sure what do you mean ? can you provide example ?

Comment: @RaynD Do you mean you want to be able to do something like `log.Println(levels.Error, "bla bla")`?

Comment: @EmilePels - what is "levels.Error, " you cannot compile it...

Comment: @RaynD Obviously... everybody is still trying to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: @EmilePels - I think the answer is the direction ...see my comments please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use a more proper logger like [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) or [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus). Also prefer passing the logger explicitly as an argument and avoid global loggers.

Yet if the exact logging workflow with the built-in one is needed, with the provided sample output, it's possible to define them with proper prefixes, instead of repeating the level in each string:

```
var (
    warnlog  = log.New(os.Stderr, "[ warn  ]", log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    infolog  = log.New(os.Stderr, "[ info  ]", log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    buildlog = log.New(os.Stderr, "[ build ]", log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    errlog   = log.New(os.Stderr, "[ error ]", log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
)
```

Comment: Thanks 1+, two questions :)  I want to use logrus how would you use it in logrus for the same purpose ? 2. you tell to pass it as argument instead of global, what If I've file that 10 func need the logrus so should I pass it to all the function ??

Comment: in addition if you want to use your example in two diffrent packages in the same application, how would you do it?

Comment: Just to make it clear, when I talking about packages, im talking only about my app packages , not others

Comment: From last to first, as you put in the question, it's possible to simply put the loggers (in my answer) inside a package that all other packages will use. You can group functions by defining a struct. Putting the logger inside the struct will make it available for that group of functions. To be honest, there are occasions that I myself find the global logger more convenient.

Comment: it will be great if you can also provide example how to do the same in logrus. thanks!

Comment: I've used zap mostly. But with zap or logrus you don't need to do that! They already have methods for leveled logging (`Error(...)`, `Info(...)`, `Warn(...)`, etc).